# sql columns by field value - is it possible?

Tags: sql, postgresql, calculated-columns

I have this query in PostgreSQL

```
SELECT numeric_value, entity_id
FROM data_value
WHERE
 entity_id = 16029 OR
 entity_id = 16026 OR
 entity_id = 33768 AND
 category_id = 158
```

The important thing to me is the numeric value, but I would like to display in this format:

```
16029 | 16026 | 33768
value | value | value
value | value | value
```

Is this possible somehow? Or it's effective? Because I have to work on a very slow server and I want to optimize as well as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you missed parenthesis in your query, should it be something like this:

```
select
    numeric_value, entity_id
from data_value
where
    entity_id in (16029, 16026, 33768) and
    category_id = 158
```

Anyway, you can easily pivot data by hand with aggregates (you just have to specify key if you want to get more than one row, it's not clear from your question how values should  be grouped together):

```
select
    --<some key>,
    max(case when entity_id = 16029 then numeric_value end) as 16029,
    max(case when entity_id = 16026 then numeric_value end) as 16026,
    max(case when entity_id = 33768 then numeric_value end) as 33768
from data_value
where
    entity_id in (16029, 16026, 33768) and
    category_id = 158
--group by <some key>
```

Comment: Sadly this query not doing what I need. The dates in the database are from different date for each entity and I have to search that date where from I have data for all entity. I wrote a subquery for this you can find it under the answer of Lajos Veres That's what my subquery does, but your query return me all available data. If I could put my subquery into this solution in that way than it runs only once it can help on me.

Comment: @LeventeKálmán don't know where to put your subquery, but it could be rewritten as `and dated >= (select max(dated) from (select min(dated) as dated from market_data.data_value where entity_id in (16029, 16026, 33768, ,16064) group by entity_id)`

Comment: I choose your answer to the best one, because this was the fastest and simplest method and finally this is what I used. Thax for everybody who helped on me.

Answer (score 2):

Should be possible to create that result using the [crosstab](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html) function.

Not the easiest part of Postgres, so be prepared to spend some time reading the docs and experimenting :)

As I think it's not immediately obvious from the doc: tablefunc is the extension containing crosstab.  Extensions are not installed by default, use [`CREATE EXTENSION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createextension.html) to install them.

Comment: Thank you, as I see this could resolve to me, but I haven't time to do it, and the server is so slow and I have so much data, than I haven't time to run so much query as required to it on this way. But thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
select
        a.value,
        b.value,
        c.value
from
        (select numeric_value as value from data_value where entity_id=16029 AND category_id =158) a,
        (select numeric_value as value from data_value where entity_id=16026 AND category_id =158) b,
        (select numeric_value as value from data_value where entity_id =33768 AND category_id =158) c
```

Comment: Not a resolution because I have an additional condition with a subquery:`AND 
dated >= (SELECT MAX(min) FROM (SELECT MIN(dated) as min FROM market_data.data_value WHERE entity_id=16029 UNION SELECT MIN(dated) as min FROM market_data.data_value WHERE entity_id=16026 UNION SELECT MIN(dated) as min FROM market_data.data_value WHERE entity_id=33768 UNION SELECT MIN(dated) as min FROM market_data.data_value WHERE entity_id=16034 UNION SELECT MIN(dated) as min FROM market_data.data_value WHERE entity_id=16064) AS date)` and it became to slow. It's faster to parse it from the script.

Comment: But I left it out, because it was irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe comibining with this WITH feature: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html ?